# Using COALESCE() function in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below query where I'm using the `COALESCE()` function in SQL. I want my query to return the text 'No Notes Maintained' if it does not finds anything in the NOTES column of the LOOKUP_TABLE. The query is returning blank when it does not finds any value, and not the desired value.

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), NOTES),'No Notes Maintained') AS NOTES 
FROM
    LOOKUP_TABLE LT
INNER JOIN 
    LOOKUP_VALUE LV ON LT.ID = LV.ID
```

The datatype of the `NOTES` column is `varchar`and it could contain a NULL, blank value or any text string, like - This is a note.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you do something like this: `SELECT CASE WHEN Notes IS NULL OR LEN(Notes)=0 THEN 'No Notes Maintained' ELSE Notes END AS TheNotes`

Comment: What are the NOTES values in your table? COALESCE() returns the first non-null value. <Blank> or an empty string is not null, so just guessing that the value is just empty and not null.

Comment: Bear in mind that `NULL` and an empty string are two different things.

Comment: @SteveP Hi Steve, thanks for your response.  I just updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you apply `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max)`?

This will return what you need:

```
CASE WHEN NOTES <> '' THEN NOTES ELSE 'No Notes Maintained' END) AS NOTES
```

`NOTES <> ''` covers NULLs, empty strings and blanks.

Comment: thank you so much. this seems to be so much simpler and works well.

Comment: @Newbie: When you think this answer sovles your question you should *accept* it.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments have suggested, if you have whitespace in the `NOTES` column, then `COALESCE` won't replace the value, because it is not null.  If you want to treat `NULL` and space as the same thing, i.e. a logical missing value, then try the following query:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),
        CASE WHEN COALESCE(REPLACE(NOTES, ' ', ''), '') = ''
             THEN 'No Notes Maintained'
             ELSE NOTES END) AS NOTESNOTES 
FROM LOOKUP_TABLE LT
INNER JOIN LOOKUP_VALUE LV
    ON LT.ID = LV.ID;
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen. Will your script also return 'No Notes Maintained' in case it finds a NULL? I would indeed like to treat NULL and space as the same.

Comment: @Newbie Yes, it would, [check the demo](http://rextester.com/RMRK20935).

Answer (score 1):

Try this should help:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), NOTES),'')!='' THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), NOTES) ELSE'No Notes Maintained' END AS NOTES 
FROM   LOOKUP_TABLE LT
  INNER JOIN LOOKUP_VALUE LV ON LT.ID = LV.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the note field can be NULL, blank or empty string, the following code should return your desired results:

```
SELECT     
    CONVERT( NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    CASE 
        WHEN ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(NOTES), '')) = '' THEN 'No Notes Maintained'
        ELSE NOTES
    END) AS NOTES 
FROM
    LOOKUP_TABLE LT
INNER JOIN 
    LOOKUP_VALUE LV ON LT.ID = LV.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This.**

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(column_name)), ''), 'Display Text')
FROM TableName
```

Explanation: You can remove the whitespace from both sides of a string using `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` together. When a string has only whitespaces, this will return an empty string value (Not a null value).

Then using `NULLIF()` function, you can compare two expressions. If expr1 and expr2 are equal, the `NULLIF()` function returns `NULL`. Otherwise, it returns expr1. In this case, when the string is an empty value, it will return NULL since it's being compared to an empty string.

Finally, you can return an alternative value when an expression is `NULL` using `ISNULL()` function.

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(LT.NOTES)), ''), 'No Notes Maintained') 
FROM
    LOOKUP_TABLE LT
INNER JOIN 
    LOOKUP_VALUE LV ON LT.ID = LV.ID
```

**OR you can do something like this...**

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN Len(column_name) > 0 THEN column_name -- Covers NULL, Empty Strings and Whitespaces.
    ELSE 'Display Text'
END
FROM TableName;
```

In your case, the query will be like this.

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN Len(LT.NOTES) > 0 THEN LT.NOTES
    ELSE 'No Notes Maintained'
END
FROM 
    LOOKUP_TABLE LT
INNER JOIN 
    LOOKUP_VALUE LV ON LT.ID = LV.ID
```